# Targeting Chrome on Android

Tags: css

I've noticed that the CSS on mobile devices needs some fixing, and I was wondering whether it's possible to target CSS for Chrome on Android?

Answer (score 1):

i know android use different densities: low, medium and high. You can target each of these very easily with the following media queries

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio:.75){
    /* Put CSS for low density (ldpi) Android layouts in here */
}

@media only screen and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio:1){
    /* Put CSS for medium density (mdpi) Android layouts in here */
}

@media only screen and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio:1.5){
    /* Put CSS for high density (hdpi) Android layouts in here */
}
```

And you can target Safari and Chrome with

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Seems this will not differentiate between Firefox Android and Chrome Android.